# How do you manage host CPU and docker containers?

Tags: docker, containers, cpu-usage

If I have a host with 4 CPUs.
How many docker containers can I run in parallel?
Is the CPU shared between the docker containers when they run?
Thanks!
Elad.

Comment: CPU is shared, it depends on what these containers are doing how many you can run without overloading the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the containers and what they do. The CPU is normally shared and used without limits, but you can impose [CPU constraints](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#cpu). That way you can keep a single container from consuming all the resources for the others.